# Button with Jquery function is not working?

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

I am probably overlooking a little thing here, but can someone please tell me why the text in the `div` is not changing when I press the button??

```
<body>
   <div id="testing">Hello Again :-)</div>
   <br/><br/>
   <button onclick="changingText()">Change Me!</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changingText()
    {
        //This is the setter of the innerHTML property in jQuery
        $('#testing').html('Hello World');

        //This is the getter of the innerHTML property in jQuery
        //var helloWorld = $('#output').html();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: do u have call the jquery library?

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: you script is fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n5p2yoh6/1/

Comment: Man I feel stupid - I forgot the library.....

Comment: I had expected.. lol :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
   <div id="testing">Hello Again :-)</div>
   <br/><br/>
   <button onclick="changingText()">Change Me!</button>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#btnChangeText').click(function (event) {
             $('#testing').html('Hello World');
             event.preventDefault();
         });
     });
 </script>

</body>
```

Please let me know if any thing goes wrong. 
Thanks